# DRBD Parse error: got 'incon-degr-cmd' (TK 282) on CentOS

Tags: linux, drbd

**Setup**

I currently have two NFS servers. And the plan is that they mirror their data to each other in realtime using DRBD and monitor each other using heartbeat.

**This is my current `/etc/drbd.d/t0.res` config.**

```
resource t0 {

 protocol C;
 incon-degr-cmd "halt -f";

 startup {
    degr-wfc-timeout 120;    # 2 minutes.
  }

  disk {
    on-io-error   detach;
  }

  net {

  }

  syncer {

    rate 10M;

    group 1;

    al-extents 257;
  }

 on node1 {                
   device     /dev/drbd0;        
   disk       /dev/loop0;         
   address    172.16.2.101:7788; 
   meta-disk  internal;      
  }

 on node2 {               
   device    /dev/drbd0;         
   disk      /dev/loop0;         
   address   172.16.2.102:7788;  
   meta-disk internal;       
  }

}
```

**Error**
When I try to use a drbdadm command I get the following error:

```
drbd.d/contentserver.res:4: Parse error: 'protocol | on | disk | net | syncer | startup | handlers | ignore-on | stacked-on-top-of' expected,
        but got 'incon-degr-cmd' (TK 282)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your resource file should read like this:

```
 resource t0 {

 protocol C;
 pri-on-incon-degr "halt -f";

 startup {
    degr-wfc-timeout 120;    # 2 minutes.
  }

  disk {
    on-io-error   detach;
  }

  net {

  }

  syncer {

    rate 10M;

    group 1;

    al-extents 257;
  }

 on node1 {                
   device     /dev/drbd0;        
   disk       /dev/loop0;         
   address    172.16.2.101:7788; 
   meta-disk  internal;      
  }

 on node2 {               
   device    /dev/drbd0;         
   disk      /dev/loop0;         
   address   172.16.2.102:7788;  
   meta-disk internal;       
  }

}
```